# How do I use imagick to find all images that are not sized 600x300 in my current folder and all its subdirectories?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I want to find all images that are NOT equal to a size (600x300) in my current folder and all subdirectories. What should I do?

I tried this but it's not working:

`find . -iname "*.png" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1<>600 && $2<>300'`

I also tried this, but the terminal got stuck for more than half an hour:

`find . -iname "*.png" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1!=600 && $2!=300'`

Comment: Try: `find . -iname "*.png" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | grep -v "600,300" `

Comment: I tried it. Still got stuck. Is it because I have too many files? (about 3,000-4,000 files in 500-600 directoires)

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you've that many files than you should expect lags and freezes.